# A List implementation that is optimised for remove(int index)

Tags: java, list, time-complexity

I want to use a `List<E>` but the only method I'm ever going to use is

```
E remove(int index)
```

I am interested in the return value of this method (the `E` removed). I never need the method `remove(E e)`.

The only constructor I'll ever need is one taking a `Collection<? extends E>`.

If `List` is an `ArrayList`, the `remove(int index)` method has time complexity O(n) because you have to shuffle the elements after the removed element one place to the left.

If `List` is a `LinkedList`, the `remove(int index)` method also has time complexity O(n) because although it takes O(1) time to change the links at an element, you have to find the element at index `index` by transversing the `List`.

If I'm only interested in using the `remove(int index)` method, is it possible to write an implementation of `List<E>` that it optimised for this method, so that the `remove(int index)` method has time complexity better than O(n)?

Comment: Yes, a tree-based structure could support it in O(log n).

Comment: Can you give me a link or more details?

Comment: A quick google search turns up http://www.nayuki.io/page/avl-tree-list

Comment: @LouisWasserman Great thank you. If you want the rep, put that link as an answer and I'll accept and upvote.

Comment: Like a Array where you mark deleted items as deleted and do not rearrange the array?

Comment: If you don't want do the implementation on your own. You could use a TreeMap<Integer, E> (Remove: O(n log n) with passing the index as key. Although when u remove any value, this specific Index will be missing. But as a TreeMap is a "NagivableMap", u can iterate in both directions. Maybe this is sufficient for you. (Same would be possible with a HashMap (Remove: almost O(1) - bit then it is not navigable anymore)

Comment: Note also that a `LinkedHashMap<Integer, E>` gives you O(1) removal.  Obviously it isn't a `List`, and therefore is not an answer to your specific question, but I suspect many use-cases looking for fast removal from a `List` would be cleaner with a `Map` or `Set` instead.

Comment: That page isn't easy to find via Google. I wonder what search terms you used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using the [TreeList](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/list/TreeList.html) from apache's commons-collections.

It is optimized such that

> This list implementation utilises a tree structure internally to ensure that all insertions and removals are O(log n).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `TreeList`. While Java does not have a implementation of it, you can use [Apache Commons TreeList](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/list/TreeList.html). You can check that it is intent to be performant on insert and removes at the middle of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about a change in ordering, you can do removal in O(1) with an array by swapping the element to remove with the last element.

As an example,

```
@Override
public E remove(int index) {
    int size = size();
    if(index < 0 || size <= index) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(String.valueOf(index));
    }

    E last = super.remove(size - 1);
    return set(index, last);
}
```

(However, note that this behaves other than is specified by the `List` interface.)